# What does "great" modify in "A great American consulting firm official"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, possessives, ambiguity, parsing

> A great American consulting firm official

What does this "great" modify?
Could it modify "consulting firm?"

I think it can only modify "official".
If it can modify "firm", then it should be

> A great American consulting firm's official

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be modifying *consulting firm* **or** it can be modifying *official*.

Consulting firm is a noun which is restricting the sort of official, another noun, that we are discussing.

American is describing one of the nouns.  Although the same word could be used as a noun in a different phrasing.

Great is describing one of the nouns.

If you wanted to be truly unambiguous...

> That great American is an official at a consulting firm.

The American [person] is [acting as] an official at a consulting firm.

> He is an official at a great American consulting firm.

The consulting firm is both great and American, and he is an official there.

> He is a great American official at that consulting firm.

That official is both great and [an] American [person], and he officiates at that consulting firm.

This sort of ambiguity is not uncommon:

> For sale : Queen Anne table by nice lady. With nice legs and big drawers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem here.  A group of adjectives modifies the noun "firm" (a great American consulting firm).  The official belongs to the above-mentioned firm.  "A great American consulting firm" functions as an attribute to the noun "official".

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more possibilities.

There are theme parks named "Great America".  It is possible that

> A Great American consulting firm official

is an official who works for a consulting firm that does work for the Great America company.  Or the Great America company could own a consulting firm, and the official could work for that consulting firm.